# Dúvidas para subir aplicação no Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Eu estou tentando subir uma aplicação web que eu fiz, através do Tomcat. Gerei o arquivo `WAR` do meu projeto onde contém a parte do Back-end, e gerei os arquivos do angular (Front-end).

Eu já instalei o Tomcat na minha máquina, e ele está funcionando normalmente, quando abro a página padrão (`localhost:8080`).

Eu coloquei o arquivo do Front dentro da pasta do Tomcat, e o arquivo do Back dentro da pasta `WebApps`, porém quando acesso no navegador, ocorre o erro 404. Acredito que esteja fazendo algo errado.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: onde é o lugar correto para colocar os arquivos do projeto que eu gerei? E após colocar nas pastas corretas, o que preciso fazer?

Comment: Se a resposta funcionou, aceite ela como a resposta de sua pergunta. Caso contrario diga o que ouve de errado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de terminada a sua aplicação e gerado o arquivo .war você deve seguir esses passos:

No meu caso eu instalei o toncat no diretório:

**C:\apache-tomcat-9**

Você deve colocar o arquivo .war dentro do diretório webapps:

**C:\apache-tomcat-9\webapps**

Depois vá ate o diretorio \bin:

**C:\apache-tomcat-9\bin**

Click em qualquer um desses arquivos para iniciar o servidor tomcat e automaticamente iniciar sua aplicação:

**startup.bat**

ou

**startup.sh**

Agora é so abrir o browser na porta 8080 seguido do nome do seu arquivo .war:

**http://localhost:8080/**

Vamos supor que sua aplicação se chame MeuApp que gerou o arquivo MeuApp.war

Para acessar ela no browser vai ficar assim:

**http://localhost:8080/MeuApp**

Uma opção seria:

Para aplicação frontend você vai ter que usar um servidor que suporte o angular (NODE) e vai ter usar uma outra porta para esse servidor do angular. Porque a localhost:8080 vai estar sendo usada pelo tomcat.

Você vai ter que ter dois servidores um é o cliente(angular) o outro é o servidor backend(tomcat).(Esse é meu modo de ver uma possível solução, talvez seja possível colocar o front e o backend tudo no tomcat mesmo)

Assim inicialize primeiro o tomcat e depois o angular em outro servidor.

Você apenas tem que configurar as chamadas do angular para o endereço certo do tomcat.

PS: Se souber inglês de uma olhada [aqui](http://www.thejavageek.com/2018/01/04/deploying-angular-app-tomcat/) para um tutorial que ensina a implantar uma aplicação angular no tomcat! Contradizendo o que eu havia dito sobre colocar em servidores separados.

Comment: Ao acessar ele no browser, dá o seguinte erro: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Lembrando que eu tenho dois projetos separados, um do BackEnd e o outro do FrontEnd. O do BackEnd eu gerei um arquivo war. O do Front eu gerei através do "ng build" do angular.

Comment: Sim, utilizo o Maven

Comment: Bem eu só ensinei como imnplantar no tomcat...Qual o servidor que voce costuma usar para as suas aplicações angular?

Comment: Então, na verdade essa foi a primeira aplicação web que fiz, e para poder utilizá-la, apenas executo o projeto e abro o meu browser. Faço chamadas REST para o back end (onde utilizo o Spring Boot). Até aí sem muita complicação. A minha intenção era poder subir a aplicação no Tomcat, para não precisar ficar executando os projetos todas as vezes.

Comment: Entendi, vou dar uma olhada melhor em como proceder com essa situação. Bem que eu achei estranho apenas colocar na pasta do Tomcat e ele funcionar... seria fácil demais se fosse assim. Agradeço a ajuda...

Comment: @De uma olhada com calma nos links que te passei.. parece fácil o precedimento. Se a resposta ajudou de um voto nela ai ou aceite com a resposta :)! Ate mais. Se puder Coloca no github seu projeto.

Comment: Opa, pode deixar! Link do github: FRONT: https://github.com/GustavoZaffani/projetoClient BACK: https://github.com/GustavoZaffani/commerce Vlw, até mais